# Getting dynamic content of Webpage from a native Webview

Tags: javascript, android, swift, ajax, webview

I have an eCommerce (website) and a very simple mobile App built for both iOS and Android with just a tab bar menu (with a shopping cart icon, profile icon, refresh button, etc.) and a Webview. The App's Webview just opens the eCommerce url in order to present the Website.

Ok, so there's the Website shopping cart button that shows, using a small icon, the number of items the cart has stored at that very moment.

My question is: is there any **easy** way to get this number from the Website (eCommerce) and load it into the native (iOS/Android) tab-bar menu? Let's say a customer adds a product, I want to reflect this at the same time on both, the eCommerce shopping cart icon (already done) and the App tab-bar's shopping cart icon.

Hope I explained well... Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

you can simply implement an api in server side which return the number of items in the cart and call that api when Website shopping cart button is clicked.

Comment: Thanks for the approach!